# Based on the number in one cell, I want to use Google Script Editor send an email with the name from the adjacent cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to send an email when a cell in column B reaches 5. However, I want part of the email to have the individual's name from column A. Here's my code so far:

```
function ifstatement() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Total");
var value = sheet.getRange("B3:B241").getValue();
if(value === 5) { 
  MailApp.sendEmail("jdoe@gmail.com", "Update", "Hi," name "are you alright?");
   }
}
```

I'm trying to define the variable "name" so that it adds the person's name from column A. Could anyone please help me!

Comment: Clearly not an Excel question - please don't use that tag for questions about Google sheets...

Comment: Do you have an example sheet or data set?

Comment: At first glance I'm pretty sure you require a string concatenation operator between **name** and the subsequent string constant and what does `===` do?

Comment: @Jeeped he does, his strings are not concatenated correctly,  though that's not the gist of his question.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal way to get values from different ranges in a sheet is to pull all the data from the sheet as a single 2D array (A table essentially), and work through that to determine what you want to do. This avoids unnecessary complexity, and also ensures that your execution time stays low since you don't need to call the `sheet.getRange()` service multiple times.

**On String concatenation**: your string concatenation would not work. You need `+` between the strings. Go from `"Hi," name "are you alright?"` to `"Hi, "+ name +" are you alright?"`.

**Here is an example solution for you:**

Using this example data:

[image]

**Note**: You don't need to know how the `columns` bit works, just how to use it, think of it as a small service to make life easier if you ever decide to add, or rearrange the spreadsheet's columns.

```
/*
 * Run this to check the sheets values
 * This is more verbose to aid with understanding
 */
function checkSheet() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Total');
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var columns = getColumnHeaders(values);

  //Loop through all the rows in the sheet and check if the 'Number' column is 5
  for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
    var number = values[i][columns['Number']]; //Get the number from the table of values, utalizing the columns object to get the index
    if(number === 5){
      var name = values[i][columns['Name']];
      var email = values[i][columns['Email']];
      Logger.log(name);
      Logger.log(email);

      //MailApp.sendEmail(email, "Update", "Hi, "+ name +" are you alright?");
    }
  }
}

/*
 * Generates a columns object that lets you reference columns by name instead of index
 * Can be used like column['headerText'] to get the index of a column
 * Is just a dynamic convenience to avoid referencing columns by index
 */
function getColumnHeaders(array){
  var columns = {};

  for(var i = 0; i < array[0].length; i++){
    columns[array[0][i]] = i;
  }
  return columns;
}
```

**Condensed `checkSheet()`:**

```
//Condensed version
function checkSheet2() {
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Total').getDataRange().getValues();
  var columns = getColumnHeaders(values);

  for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
    if(Number(values[i][columns['Number']]) === 5){
      //MailApp.sendEmail(values[i][columns['Email']], "Update", "Hi, "+ values[i][columns['Name']] +" are you alright?");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At this line:

```
var value = sheet.getRange("B3:B241").getValue();
```

You're using the method [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) and it only returns the value of the top-left cell of the range, and you need to to get the values of the whole column A an B, so first set the range to `A3:B241` then use the method [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) to get the values as a two-dimensional array. The line should look like this:

```
var values = sheet.getRange("A3:B241").getValues();
```

Once you have the [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) you need to loop through the values and check if the element at the index 1 `values[i][1]` is equal to 5. The line should look like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  if(values[i][1] === 5){
     // Block of code to be executed if the condition is true
  }
}
```

Finally, the configuration of paramaters you're using for the [sendEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient-subject-body) method is: `(recipient, subject, body)`  the body of the message needs to be a String, you need to concatenate the `"Hi,"`, the name that is in the index 1 `values[i][1]` and `"are you alright?"`, to achieve that you need to use the the concatenation operator (`+`), the line should look like this:

```
MailApp.sendEmail("jdoe@gmail.com", "Update", "Hi," + values[i][0] + " are you alright?");
```

The complete code:

```
function ifstatement() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Total");
  var values = sheet.getRange("A3:B241").getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if(values[i][1] === 5){
       MailApp.sendEmail("jdoe@gmail.com", "Update", "Hi," + values[i][0] + " are you alright?");
    }
  }
```